# Is it possible to use postgis_raster extension in CloudSQL?

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, postgis, google-cloud-sql, raster

I'm trying to import a postgreSQL database of rasters to CloudSQL in order to do raster analysis on them from the cloud. I'm trying

```
CREATE EXTENSION postgis_raster;
```

but getting the following error

```
ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/share/extension/postgis_raster.control": No such file or 
directory
```

I'm assuming that there just isn't any support for postgis_raster on CloudSQL, but I can't find any specific information on it. For now I guess I'll just convert my rasters to point shapefiles. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right about postgis_raster. Still, there is an [Extension support: postgis_raster](https://issuetracker.google.com/158743777) in the [Public Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/). You may follow related developments in that thread.

Comment: Thank you, I'll make sure to keep an eye on that!